# CSS animation on page load

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Why is the following code not animated when the page loads?

```css
#error {
    opacity: 0 text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.animate {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="error" class="animate">This is an error message!</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply both styles at the same time if you want there to be an animation.

To accomplish this you can use JavaScript to apply the `opacity` property after the page has loaded.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("error").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
#error {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    line-height:1.5;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="error">This is an error message!</div>
```